# Nested ordered list embedded conditionally

Tags: html, list, nested

I have the following html in which I'm conditionally embedding an ol or ul. I like to see the embedded list become a contiguous list at least in appearance in the final output. What kind of CSS styling can I use to achieve this?

```
<ol>
  <li>Coffee
  <! -- embedded unordered or ordered list - begin -->
  <ul>
    <li>Apple</li>
    <li>Orange</li>
    </ul>
  <! -- embedded unordered or ordered list - end -->
  </li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>
```

HTML Output:

```
1. Coffee
   . Apple
   . Orange
2. Tea
3. Milk
```

Required Output:

```
1. Coffee
2. Apple
3. Orange
4. Tea
5. Milk
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to involve Javascript in order to accomplish this.

Try this bit of jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('ol li').each(function(index) {
        $('li:has(ul li)').after(this);
    });
});
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b3Has/)